# can't center align text when using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm building an Ionic app, but have run into a minor problem that I don't understand and can't seem to resolve.

I have a ion-item that is hardcoded and an ion-item that is generated using ng-repeat. I'm using css to center the text in both of them, however, the ion-item generated using ng-repeat is slightly more to the left compared to the hardcoded one.
It seems to only be a problem when I'm using ion-view and templates. If I move the code to index.html they are both centered correctly.

Any ideas to what is causing it and what I can do to fix it?

link to plunker: [plnkr.co/edit/tUM7pL54OlyCQwr2qu3o?p=preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/tUM7pL54OlyCQwr2qu3o?p=preview)

Html Structure:

```
<ion-view title="Home">
      <ion-content>
        <div id="menu">          
              <ion-list>
                  <ion-item class="item-trns">
                  test
                  </ion-item>
                  <ion-item class="item-trns">
                  more test
                  </ion-item>
              </ion-list>
        </div>

        <div id="categories">

              <ion-list ng-controller="CatCtrl">
                  <ion-item class="item-trns" ng-repeat="category in categories" ui-sref='{{category.view}}'>
                  {{category.title}}  
                  </ion-item>
              </ion-list>
        </div>
      </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Thanks,
Kasper

Comment: link to plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/tUM7pL54OlyCQwr2qu3o?p=preview

Comment: Do put the link into the post. Best place would be right after the first sentence. It makes your question much clearer for anybody else. Beyond that I can't help you with your problem.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind for next time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is `ui-sref` tag, it add "item-content" class to your auto generated ion items, this class adds `padding: 16px 49px 16px 16px;` to your elements. If you remove the `ui-sref`, your generated ion-items will be centered.

Comment: Yup, removing that in the plunker link provided by @kandersen works.

Answer (score 0):

The `ui-sref` directive creates a `<a>` into each `<ion-list>`
if you whish to align both, you need to adapt CSS if the freshly created element without padding

By adding this class, you can overide the default style and keep your ui-sref

```
a.item-content {
  padding-left:0px !important;
  padding-right:0px !important;
}
```